# Getting elements with dynamic range of list in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get the elements of a list in python but with a dynamic range ie if I have `two lists ['9','e','s','t','1','2','3'] and ['9','e','1','2','3','s','t']` now I need to access the three numbers including 1, so what I did was reached for 1 and then pass the index value of 1 and extract the desired values ie

```
s_point = valueList.index('1')
print (valueList[s_point::3]
```

but it does not seem to work however on const values like

```
print (valueList[1::3])
```

it seems to work just fine. is there a way I could dynamically pass range of list elements to extract out of list ?

Comment: Not sure if you have the string '1' on the list, it looks like an integer from here...

Comment: Please avoid the missing quotes that are strings.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "avoid the missing quotes". If there are quotes in your quote - please fix your post to include accurate information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the three items after the `s_point` index you don't have to use the `step` which is `::step` because the usage is different. Just change your line to this:

```
valueList[s_point:s_point+3]
```

output:

```
>>> [1,2,3]
```

This way it is going to get the sublist of `valueList` from the index of `s_point` to the three which are front of it.

And to know the usage of `step` as other websites mentioned:

> The step is a difference between each number in the result. The
>   default value of the step is 1 if not specified

For example:

```
valueList[::2]
```

result:

```
>>> ['9','s','1','3']
```

As you see the odd items are not in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need

```
lst = ['9', 'e', '1', '2', '3', 's', 't']
print(lst[lst.index('1'):lst.index('1') + 3])

lst1 = ['9', 'e', 's', 't', '1', '2', '3']
print(lst1[lst1.index('1'):lst1.index('1') +3])
```

**Output:**

```
['1', '2', '3']
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems

1) `s_point = valueList.index('1')
print (valueList[s_point::3]`

but it does not seem to work,

This is simply because you missed the ending parentheses of the print statement.

2) However, on const values like 1 in this example

print (valueList[1::3]) works

but it will not give the desired output rather prints the first 3 numbers.

3) Assuming when the list valuelist is defined, the alphabets used is in single quotes.

Now for the actual solution part.

If you are looking for the case wherein you need the value 1 or any dynamic value say x and the subsequent three values after that from the list. You can make use of a function or anonymous function called `lambda`, which should accept a dynamic parameter, and it should return the subsequent 3 or dynamic values. like shown below.

```
>>>
>>> valuelist = [9, 'e', 's', 't', 1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> result = lambda x,y: valuelist[valuelist.index(x):valuelist.index(x)+y]
>>> result(1,3)
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>>
```